# Open a shapefile from a folder and merge maps to create a model

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I'm new to QGIS. I don't know how to script in Python, so I'd like to create a model using the graphical modeler tool in QGIS. I would like my model to allow me to fetch directly from a shapefile (different parcel maps, i.e. polygons) to merge them together and make a single map.

Do you know how I can do this, knowing that I've found that "right-click in the work area and select "Add an algorithm" > "General vector" > "Load a vector layer". This will add an algorithm block to your model, but when I right-click in the modeler work area nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you but if you want to be able to select a number of shapefiles and merge them, this should work:

1. Add a `Multiple input parameter` with allowed layer type File
2. Set it as input to `Merge vector layers`

[image]